# gphoto2 in Python vs command line; not able to capture preview in Python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, libgphoto2

I've worked with gphoto2 (2.5.20, on a RPi) before, and have been able to do the basics from the command line:

/usr/bin/gphoto2 --capture-image-and-download --filename=zzz.jpg --force-overwrite

/usr/bin/gphoto2 --capture-preview --filename=zzz.jpg --force-overwrite

The latter captures the preview image, which is a great deal smaller, and for some applications, is great; you can essentially make a webcam out of a DSLR.

However, after installing the gphoto2 library for python, this (which should be the equivalent) fails:

```
import gphoto2 as gp
camera = gp.Camera()
camera.init()
file_path = camera.capture(gp.GP_OPERATION_CAPTURE_PREVIEW)
```

with the message "gphoto2.GPhoto2Error: [-6] Unsupported operation"

If you choose

```
file_path = camera.capture(gp.GP_CAPTURE_IMAGE)
```

however, this works.   Any reasons why we might get a working preview from the command line, and not in the Python version?

`gp.__version__` returns 2.2.2 , and matches the latest release at https://github.com/jim-easterbrook/python-gphoto2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I drilled down into the libgphoto2 source.  The cameras I have fall under the PTP world; I believe this is in camlibs/ptp2/library.c, where the camera_capture_preview function is located.  The Python code fails with both a Nikon and Sony.  There do seem to be two things in the code which point to possible issues; in the Nikon section, it will try 20 times to get the preview; in the Sony section, there are comments regarding timing.  However, the command line works, so the problem may not have been there.

I looked at the gphoto2 implementation in Python as well.  The good news is that the code at https://github.com/jim-easterbrook/python-gphoto2/blob/master/examples/preview-image.py works, so if anyone wants to do this in Python, they can replace the

file_path = camera.capture(gp.GP_OPERATION_CAPTURE_PREVIEW) line

with the code there.

Note that this worked on the rPi with gphoto2 (2.5.20); on an Ubuntu 16.04 LTS system, this fails (gphoto2 is 2.5.9).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the gphoto2 program source. You might be able to find out what sequence of libgphoto2 functions the `--capture-preview` command calls. You should then be able to reproduce that in Python.